Can you identify/explain the wiring in my bathroom based on this diagram?
I'm in USA. I'm changing an old bathroom light/exhaust fan out. The image below is of the ceiling, and the connection to the light/fan. 
Image of how switch is wired. Not of actual switch 
Cables/Wires/Connections
Single Pole Light Switch
-A black wire on the top screw, connection uncertain
-A white wire on the bottom screw, connection uncertain
Light/Fan Unit
-A black wire, connection uncertain
A white wire, connection uncertain
Wires in the ceiling
-A black wire, known connection to the light switch, unknown to which
-A white wire that has been tested hot, known connection to the light/fan unit, unknown to which

i would like to replace the switch with a new switch, to take advantage of the independent fan and humidity sensor controls, like pictured below.

switch two and three only work when switch one is turned on. can i rewire it to be simply hot(white) to switch, and neutral(black) to fan/light neutral? picture here. 
Thanks kindly for any and all help. I appreciate it.

Your diagram and description are both confusing. Please revise to list cables, wires, and connections in a more structured way. Grounds are probably irrelevant. Photos might help. Also make sure your question is a question. It starts out as one but ends up as a rambling statement.

Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Plaes [edit] in pictures of the actual wiring as presently connected at the fan, switch, and whatever other locations it's accessible. What you have described and drawn does not add up.

@Ecnerwal i have added the photo of the ceiling wiring. I can't get a picture of the switch right now. but it's a single pole light switch with a black coming off the top screw, and a white coming off the bottom screw.

You have three wires labeled "connected to switch", but only two wires are actually connected to the switch?  Is there only one switch?  Why do you think the three labeled wires are connected to the switch?  Two wires in the ceiling include the description "unknown to which" - what does that mean?

@Mark the third wire, ground, is connected to switch, but i was told it was likely irrelevant so i didn't include. there is only one switch. i know they are connected to the switch. the ground i understand. "unknown to which" i do not the connection that is being made. the confusion for me is for the other two "connected to switch", they used loose red wire to extend them, before then connecting them to romex 14/2. due to walls in the way it can't be traced directly. adding to the confusion, is that the white in the ceiling is hot and goes directly to the light/fan unit.

@TimmyTimson Can you see where the loose wires are connected to the Romex, or is that buried in a wall somewhere?  Does the existing fan/light work, or did it used to work?  Is the cable at the bottom of your photo connected to the existing fan/light?  It appears to have a green wire which should be ground - can you see if that green wire is connected to the fan's metal housing?

@TimmyTimson it would help if your leader lines actually pointed to what you're intending them to point to.

@Mark the loose wire to romex connections are rather buried, i can see them faintly after pulling out the junction box. the light/fan works. the cable at the bottom is connected to the light/fan, one to black one to white. the green/ground is connected to the fan's chassis.

@TimmyTimson Okay.  The top connection in your picture appears to show a very heavy gauge black wire connected to a lighter gauge red wire and is labeled "connected to switch". Which wire is going toward the switch - the thin red one, or the thick black one?  Have you tested it for voltage?  Do you have any better way to test voltage than a non-contact "voltage pen"?  They can be unreliable.

@mark the red one is running to the switch. yes i have a multimeter. there is no voltage coming in on the black. let me edit post with a new picture that may help explain better.

@TimmyTimson The new information raises another question.  Can you provide the make and model of the fan/light unit?  Is the humidity sensor built into the fan, or is it a separate device?  If built in, does the fan/light have two switched hot connections - one for the light and one to enable the fan to operate automatically based on humidity?  Or does it have three switched hot connections - one for the light, one for the fan to operate automatically, and one for manual control of the fan?

@Mark it is a broan aer110slw. it has 3 separate leads to allow automatic and manual control of fan. thank you.

I think there's enough information to answer your question, though you'll have to verify a few things.  You won't be able to do this using the existing wiring, for several reasons:

You can't have individual wires running loose inside the walls.  They have to be contained in cables (i.e. Romex) or run in conduit.
You can't have wire connections hidden inside the wall.  Connections have to be inside an accessible electrical box.
It doesn't look like you have a ground at the fan or switch (unless there's another cable entering the switchbox).
Finally, you don't have enough wires running between the fan location and the switch to control the fan and light as you want.

I've marked up your photo to identify the apparent purpose of each of the existing wires based on your comments.

This is where you'll need to do some verifying with your multimeter.

The source on the left appears to be where power comes into this part of the circuit.  Turn the power off and disconnect the two wires attached to the black and white wires labelled as source.  Also disconnect the red wire at the bottom labelled as "switched power from switch" and the black wire labelled as "ground to switch".
Find a good ground that runs back to your breaker panel (a known
grounded outlet for example) and turn the power back on.
measure the voltage between the white wire and ground, and between the black wire and ground.  Do this twice - with the switch in both on and off positions.  You should have 120 volts on one wire and 0 volts on the other regardless of which position the switch is in.  Note which wire is hot (hopefully it's the black one).
Measure the voltage between ground and each of the wires from the switch, with the switch in both positions.  You should have 0 volts on both wires in both positions.

If these all check out, you've confirmed the source of the power, and that nothing is hot in the switch loop when it's disconnected from the source.

Turn the power off again and connect the red "always hot to switch" wire to whichever of the source wires was measured as hot.
Turn the power back on, and measure the voltage on the "switched hot from switch" wire with the switch in both positions.  You should see 120 volts with the switch on, and 0 volts with the switch off.

If these steps check out, then you've confirmed the switch loop wiring.
To make this work, you need to wire it like this:

You can see that you don't have enough wires between the fan and the switchbox.  You need:

Always hot supply to switch
Switched hot to light
Switched hot to fan auto
Switched hot to fan manual
Neutral - won't be used, but needed to meet code.  Capped off in switchbox.
Ground (not shown in diagram, but needed in every box)

I see a flexible metal conduit passing through the opening in your ceiling.  If your house is wired with conduit, you can install new conduit or extend the existing conduit from the switchbox and pull new wires through it.  You'll need to make sure it's a continuous run from the switchbox to the fan box, with no connections or individual wires hidden inside the walls.
If you use cable instead of conduit it will get more complicated because there are too many conductors for normally available cable.  I'm pretty sure you would have to run a 14/2 to bring the hot and neutral from the source into the switchbox, and a 14/4 to carry the three switched hots and a neutral back to the fan box.  I believe the neutral would have to run down and back if two cables are used because the supply and return current have to be enclosed in the same cable.
You will also need to be sure the switchbox is large enough because you're adding a lot of wires to it.
Finally, you'll need to follow the source wiring back to the box it originates in, and run new conduit or cable between there and the fan box in order to eliminate the existing individual wires and splices that are hidden within the walls, and provide a ground to the fan and switch.
